# how to count total records and repeat primary div 3 times in php

Tags: php, mysql, loops

we are working on frontend design, we want to display our div col33 for 3 times, we are fetching records from mysql and then we want to count total records, for example if records are 60, we want to display 20 records in div col33 then div col33 display 20 records and so on.

```
<div class="col33">
     <ul>
      <?php foreach ($lists as $list): ?>
       <li><a href="<?php echo site_url() . $list->page_slug; ?>"><?php echo ucfirst($list->page_name); ?></a></li>
      <?php endforeach; ?>
     </ul>
</div><!-- ending of col33 -->
```

Comment: count($lists) for total records...

Comment: You don't say whether you want the records to run across the columns or down the columns.  That will make a big difference on how this is handled

Comment: yeah, but i don't know how to create code to display total records in 3 columns, div col33

Comment: You are going to have to think about how you might do this, it is pretty basic logic, just the sort of problem you need to solve (yourself) if you are going to do some coding.

Here's a hint.  Count the records, divide the total by 3, work out how to build the columns the way you want.

Comment: Steve, thanks, yeah i knew it, how to count total records etc, but in php how to dive total records by 3?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure but I hope You want something like this:

```
<?php
$lists = array("1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","11");
$rows = ceil(count($lists) / 3);
$rowsConst = $rows;
$rows = 0; // for first div.
$first = true;
foreach ($lists as $list):

if ($rows == 0): 
    $rows = $rowsConst;
    if (!$first) {
        echo "</div>\n";
    } else {
        $first = false;
    }
?>
<div class="col33">
<ul>
    <li><a href=""><?php echo $list; ?></a></li>
</ul>
<? else: ?>
<ul>
     <li><a href=""><?php echo $list; ?></a></li>
</ul>
<? 
endif;
$rows--;
endforeach; 
?>
</div>
?>
```

**[WORKING CODE](http://codepad.org/YdmeUQgX)**

Answer (score 0):

Hey i think you want something like if you have 60 records and you want 20 records to distribute each of them in the div col33 and that should repeat 3 times. if i am right then i hope here is your solution. otherwise kindly elaborate more. cheers

```
    <div class="col33">
         <ul>
          <?php $j=1;
    foreach ($lists as $list):
    if($j%20==0){
?>
    <li><a href="<?php echo site_url() . $list->page_slug; ?>"><?php echo ucfirst($list->page_name); ?></a></li>
  <?php  }else{
<li><a href="<?php echo site_url() . $list->page_slug; ?>"><?php echo ucfirst($list->page_name); ?></a></li>

}
$j++; ?>

          <?php endforeach; ?>
         </ul>
    </div>
```